# Running Appium Android TestNG on AWS Device Farm

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, aws-device-farm

To run appium-project on AWS Device Farm, the pre-requisite is to not to set desired capabilities in the appium project. As suggested in the training video

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWAUAerFB6s.

If I don't set the capabilities, test fail on my local with error "A new session could not be created. Details: The `desiredCapabilities` object was not valid for the following reason(s): `deviceName` can't be blank."

If tests fail `zip-with-dependencies.zip` wont be created.

Note: if I set desired capabilities in appium-project, tests are failing on AWS device farm.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies that you are running into issues. We've published [a sequence of blogs posts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/test-ios-apps-on-aws-device-farm-using-appium-part-1-prerequisities-environment-set-up-and-test-creation/) that show you how to construct Appium tests to run in AWS Device Farm. In particular, Device Farm does not want you to set `DesiredCapabilities` except for the URL.

`@BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);
    }`

Comment: I used the same in my code. I see no issue in packaging the eclipse project and followed everything as specified in aws docs. (Note:- If i replace my 
quicken.apk (test app) with some sample android app it works.)

Looks like aws is unable to pick my test app actual package/activity, hence unable to start.

My test app activity & package are
appActivity - "com.mint.core.overview.RouterActivity" 
appPackage - "com.quicken.qm2014"

Comment: Appium-server-Log >>
2017-02-07 19:04:14:739 - error: Could not pre-launch appium: Error: com.quicken.qm2014/com.mint.core.overview.RouterActivity never started. Current: com.quicken.qm2014/.QkLoginActivity.

It would be really great if I could get some help on this.

Comment: You're running into issues that are specific to your app. Please either reach out through AWS Support or post on the AWS Device Farm forum, and we can help further.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create `zip-with-dependencies.zip` you can skip tests:

Go to command line and run this command

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
```

After you get a BUILD SUCCESS message, check your target directories for `zip-with-dependencies.zip` file.